# I am getting "The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to write a smart contract for jackpot game which calculates users' rate and randomly selects one user but I am getting **"The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."** error when I try to execute `sendToWinner()` function.

*Note: Please don't mind the logical errors I am aware of the logical errors this is for training my Solidity writing skills.*

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Jackpot {
    
    uint256 public pot;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    address[] public participators;
    address public minter;

    constructor(){
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function addToPot() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        pot += msg.value;
        participators.push(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        _;
    }

    function random() public view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp)))%100;
    }

    function sendToWinner() payable public onlyOwner {
        uint8[100] memory participatorsRates;
        uint8 rate;
        uint8 participatorsRatesIndex=0;
        for(uint8 participatorIndex = 0; participatorIndex<participators.length; participatorIndex++){
            rate = uint8(balances[participators[participatorIndex]]*100/pot);
            for(; participatorIndex<rate ; participatorsRatesIndex++){
                participatorsRates[participatorsRatesIndex] = participatorIndex;
            }
            balances[participators[participatorIndex]]=0;
        }
        uint8 winningParticipatorIndex = participatorsRates[random()];

        payable(participators[winningParticipatorIndex]).transfer(pot);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found out that I have used wrong variable at nested loop in `sendToWinner()` function:

```
        for(uint8 participatorIndex = 0; participatorIndex<participators.length; participatorIndex++){
            rate = uint8(balances[participators[participatorIndex]]*100/pot);
            for(; participatorIndex<rate ; participatorsRatesIndex++){
                participatorsRates[participatorsRatesIndex] = participatorIndex;
            }
            balances[participators[participatorIndex]]=0;
        }
```

For `for(; participatorIndex<rate ; participatorsRatesIndex++){` instead `participatorIndex` I should have written `participatorsRatesIndex`. Because it became infinite loop it couldn't work but now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** **payable** it's a modifier, so you have to write **after** "public"

```
`function sendToWinner() public payable onlyOwner {}`
```

**2)** don't use .transfer, use `call{value: amount}("")` instead.

so it will be:

```
function sendToWinner() public payable onlyOwner {
        uint8[100] memory participatorsRates;
        uint8 rate;
        uint8 participatorsRatesIndex=0;
        for(uint8 participatorIndex = 0; participatorIndex<participators.length; participatorIndex++){
            rate = uint8(balances[participators[participatorIndex]]*100/pot);
            for(; participatorIndex<rate ; participatorsRatesIndex++){
                participatorsRates[participatorsRatesIndex] = participatorIndex;
            }
            balances[participators[participatorIndex]]=0;
        }
        uint8 winningParticipatorIndex = participatorsRates[random()];
        (bool success, ) = payable(participators[winningParticipatorIndex]).call{value:pot}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
        
    }
```

see:
[Is transfer() still safe after the Istanbul update?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation)

https://diligence.consensys.net/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

**3)** be sure to have enough balance

Comment: Thank you for the optimization recommendation, but I managed to debug it and saw that rate doesn't change. I changed it to uint256 because I tought it may be overflowing but didn't worked. I changed the value: pot/2 to see if there is something wrong about balance but it didn't work as well.

Comment: the contract have enough balance?

Comment: yes I have written a function to see the current balance and it has enough balance inside the contract